# PowerBI - combining values and showing them in charts

Tags: powerbi

I am fairly new at PowerBI but want to use it within our Organisation a lot more frequently to get a better insight into our data.
Here is what i am currently struggling with:

I am trying to combine several individual datasets into one Group so i can Show them in a graph and compare them to other (potentially not combined Groups). 
I have tried the grouping function but this just doesn't Group any values at all, and the Graphs do not Change. Below is a pic for Illustration.

[image: Combination of hours from different departmens]

Any help is greatly appreciated

thankx!
BR
AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a new column with your needed category. On the left pane, go to **Data > Modelling > New Column** and write the following expression (assuming in YourDeptColumn values are strings):

```
NewColumn = IF(OR(YourTable[YourDeptColumn] = "Dept.1"; 
                YourTable[YourDeptColumn] = "Dept.2";
                YourTable[YourDeptColumn] = "Dept.3"
                );
              "Dept 1+2+3"; 
              "Dept 4"
              )
```

This is the result:

```
  YourDeptColumn    NewColumn
      Dept.1        Dept 1+2+3
      Dept.2        Dept 1+2+3
      Dept.3        Dept 1+2+3
      Dept.4        Dept 4
      Dept.1        Dept 1+2+3
```

Now put the NewColumn in your chart as category and the YourDeptColumn as color shade.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply!  Does this allow me then subsequently add up the "x hours" from the individual Depts.? And do i need the part for "Dept 4" ? I should mention i have like 20 other depts i don't want to sum

Comment: EDIT: thanks this worked lovely, but It seems as if i cannot combine more than two "OR" statements. Do i have to combne several OR-columns to get where i need to be?

Comment: Yes you are right, the docu says it just supports two arguments in the `OR()`. You can either stack the `OR()` function or you use a `Switch()` function. Here is a reference for the switch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax

Comment: Great, thanks! Will defo give this a try! This seems to be like the "IFS" function from excel, or am I mistaken? EDIT: Just tried it and it seems to be working as intended